# How to filter local traffic with iptables?

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking

Can iptables be used to filter local traffic?

I am confused by how this should be set up. For example, here is a diagram of how I picture the set up would be:

[image: Setup]

I just don't see how iptables would be able to intercept data that is not going to it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Need more information like IP address/subnet mask of X,Y,Z. In general, if the machines are all on the same subnet you need iptables rules on each of X,Y,Z to do any filtering. Otherwise, if the traffic is all routed, you can do so on your linux machine with iptables assuming it is the default gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a Layer 2 switch, there is no way for the Linux server to filter anything. If you have a Layer 3 switch, you could put each Machine in its own VLAN/subnet and then force all of the data to be routed through the linux server but honestly, that's quite messy.

What is your use case here?

Comment: My goal is to try and intercept data using iptables and then control the rate of transmission using tc as the data reaches its destination.

Comment: This is typically done at your router? Is the linux box your router?

Comment: No, I did not think a router is needed in my setup, as it is only dealing with the LAN, but I might be missing something.

Comment: I think it would do you well to read up on IP Network in general, and about the roles switches and routers play in networking infrastructure.

Comment: Yes, after thinking about this for a bit, I agree that the linux box should be my router. I imagine I will need to configure all machines to have a default gateway to my linux box. Please let me know if this is incorrect.

Comment: That's heading in the right direction.